# Trying to run resfinder using the command line but get raise ValueError

Tags: python, command-line, genome

the full error message I receive is: raise ValueError ("SHA could not be resolved, git returned: %r" % (header_line.strip())) ValueError: SHA could not be resolved, git returned: b''

this programme has ran previously and I have python version 3.8.6 installed in this environment but python 3.10 in another environment and neither works